# Nginx location directive not working

Tags: nginx

My Nginx config file is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location /a/ {
        return 404;
    }
    return 301;
}
```

When I run a request:

```
curl -v http://localhost/a/
```

I expect to see 404 code. But I receive 301 code.
Why `location /a/ {}` directive is not working?

Answer (score 3):

The `return` directive must be inside the `location` block, unless it is the only one in server block.

This configuration works as intended:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location /a/ {
        return 404;
    }
    location / {
        return 301;
    }
}
```